# Python regular expressoin - match string containing #expr1 and not #expr2 and not #expr3

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a string that has "subscribe"  and does not have "did not" or "unsub.*" in it.

For example,

"please subscribe me" would match

but "I did not subscribe this email" or "please unsubscribe me" would fail to match.

what I have is

```
".*subscribe(?!.*did\\s+not)(?!.*unsub.*)"
```

which apparently doesn't work.

So again, the expression I want is (A and !B and !C)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: What if the string is `don't ever subscribe me to this stinkin junk, take me off this stinkin mailing list dude!` ?

Comment: @sln Or 'How dare you subscribe me...', 'Why did you...', 'I didn't ask you to...', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your lookaheads should be at the start of the regular expression:

```
re.match(r"(?!.*did\s+not)(?!.*unsub).*subscribe", text)
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not need `^` before negative lookahead?

Comment: @Ωmega: It's not required if using match. I've added a call to match to make it clear that this is to be used with match, not search.

Comment: @Ωmega: That might be what happens in Perl, but this question is tagged Python.

Comment: That's why I am asking, as I want to learn - I believed Perl and Python would use same regex engine...

Comment: Although `match` in Python does imply the start of the string, this regex in its literal sense is unanchored.

Answer (score 0):

***Regex:***

```
^(?!.*unsub)(?!.*did not).*subscribe
```

***Python:***

```
re.match(r"^(?!.*unsub)(?!.*did not).*subscribe", str)
```

Comment: The way you have it, `did not` must not be at the start of the string. So it will match `I did not subscribe this email`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with positive and negative lookahead, but a far better approach is to have one regexp for search terms, and another for the stopwords.

```
if re.search(r"\bsubscribe", text) and not re.search(r"did\s+not|\bunsub", text):
    unsubscribe(sender)
```

Lookaheads are only worth using if you need to include/exclude text at specific positions.

Also note that the `\b` (word boundary) will keep "subscribe" from matching inside the word "unsubscribe".